# Minutes to Hour calculation

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table as attTable and column OTM is for OT Minutes

```
SELECT
    EMPID,
    OTM,
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(OTM) * 60), '%k.%i') AS OTH
FROM attTable
WHERE EMPID='1000126'
AND DATE(TimeIN) between '2023-09-26' and '2023-10-26'
GROUP BY date(TimeIN);
```

When query above code GROUPING BY date(TimeIN) i can see below result

[image: mysql]

When I query as GROUPING BY EMPID to get 1 month total hours of OT
I get below results as OTM = 4276, OTH = 71.16

```
SELECT
    EMPID,
    sum(OTM) as OTMSUM,
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(OTM) * 60), '%k.%i') AS OTH
FROM attTable
WHERE EMPID='1000126'
AND DATE(TimeIN) between '2023-09-26' and '2023-10-26'
GROUP BY empid;
```

[image: OTM 4276 and OTH 71.16]

but when I calculate it should be 67.56 but why result is 71.16, so checked in excel
individual row showing correct result but when I query sum there is wrong calculation, how can I fix this issue please see excel screenshot

[image: excel]

How can I solve this MySQL issue?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your `67.57` in the spreadsheet is the decimal sum, not sum of hh:mm. 71hrs 16mins is correct.

Comment: Please say some one tell me how resolve this issue in mysql

Comment: What issue? I have already pointed out that your calculation in Excel is incorrect, as you are treating your `h.mm` as a decimal value instead of time (`hh:mm`). The value returned by your MySQL query is correct. Please replace the images in your question with [markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) (or another text based format).

Comment: Please note, I need solution in mysql

Comment: Please don't ask for a mysql solution by referring to excel, add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: mysql converting 540 minutes as 9.0 and 33 minutes as 0.33 and 386 as 6.26 but total sum amount wrong. please check 1st picture its like 9.0+0.33+6.26= 15.59 correct answer, but result is 16.24 or 16.38 like this amount coming.

Answer (score 0):

71.16 is the correct result.
As others have pointed out before, you cannot add time as a decimal without converting it.

It appears from your screenshots you have copied the OTM and OTH into Excel but and wrote all your time in decimal format not in time. So adding it as a decimal is incorrect.

If you convert 30 minutes to a decimal, it is not 0.30, it would be 0.50 because it is half of 1 hour.

For example, you have 33 mins in Cell B3 and 56 minutes in cell B15.
You have wrote this as 0.33 and 0.56. in Cell A3 and A15

If I were to add this together like you have in Excel, it equals 0.89 hours which is not correct.
The correct answer would be 1 hour and 29 minutes.

There is nothing wrong with the SQL result and nothing to fix

Comment: mysql convert perfecly with code minutes to hours as what is want. my problem is when calculate total amount issue. mysql converting 540 minutes as 9.0 and 33 minutes as 0.33 and 386 as 6.26 but total sum amount wrong. please check 1st picture its like 9.0+0.33+6.26= 15.59 correct answer, but result is 16.24 or 16.38 like this amount coming.